# Flink Kafka integration issues

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Context:
Built a fraud detection kind of app.
Business logic is all fine, but when putting into production, Kafka cluster is becoming unstable.

The topic to which it wrote have approx 80 events/sec. post running for > 1 hours Kafka broker offsets are getting corrupted.

Which is making consumers on this broker to fail.

Haven’t find any issues with load testing on non-prod environments.

Not sure what was causing issues.

Topic config: single partition, replication 3.
Kafka version - 2.1
Flink version - 1.11.2-scala-2.12
Using same version for Kafka consumer, Kafka producer.

Any suggestions are welcomed, what can be the cause.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how the offsets are being managed: i.e., what settings are you using in Flink re checkpointing, starting offsets, consumer group, exactly-once, etc? And which consumers are failing -- the flink kafka consumers, or non-flink consumers of what is produced by flink, or other flink jobs consuming from a flink producer?

Comment: using checkpointing to manage offsets. 
starting offsets : latest
consumer group: Yes
transaction: at least once

consumer: all consumers listening to topics on that broker.

Comment: What happens that makes you say that the offsets are corrupted? And how do the consumers fail?